# Extension Method for Map in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, extension-methods

I am a novice in the Scala world!
I am trying to develop some helpers to make my life easier around Scala code.
For instance, one of the pieces that I am trying to get it to work is as below -

```
object Helpers{
  implicit class MapExt(val self: Map[String, Any]) extends AnyVal {
      // gets a map value for specified key casting as required type
      def GetValueAs[T](key: String): T = self(key).asInstanceOf[T];
  }
}
```

The logic behind this code is that I have a `String` to `Any` map that I need to cast values at run-time. What I am trying to achieve here is not important but what's important is that how we do this in Scala. How can I have an extension method that works for a specific type of generic type (in this case `Map[String, Any]`) and that method is itself a generic type. The code as above gives me a compile time error if I try to use it as -

```
myMap.GetValueAs[Date]("start_date")
```

Error: value GetValueAs is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]

Can someone please help to get just his simple example to work. That would be a great help and I appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: It works for me. Did you bring your implicit class into scope. I.e. did you `import Helpers._` before calling `myMap.GetValueAs`? That should be all that's needed.

Comment: Why do you have `extends AnyVal`? Is that meaningful, i.e. will you enjoy the benefits of it, in this case?

Comment: we don't capitalize method names in Scala. use `getValueAs` instead

Comment: since I was within the same scope I thought it would do it automatically but apparently it didn't :( Thanks for help

Comment: @KevinMeredith based on Scala documents if you don't do that it will create an object at run-time for this; otherwise, it doesn't have any other benefits!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bring your extension methods into scope, i.e. by importing them:

```
object Helpers {
  implicit class MapExt(val self: Map[String, Any]) extends AnyVal {
    // gets a map value for specified key casting as required type
    def getValueAs[A](key: String): A = self(key).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}

import Helpers._  // !
Map("foo" -> 2, "bar" -> 3.45).getValueAs[Int]("foo")  // works
```

Comment: Given: `lub( List( typeOf[Map[String, String]], typeOf[AnyVal] ) ) === Any`, isn't the `extends AnyVal` meaningless per the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)?

Comment: @KevinMeredith The `extend AnyVal` has nothing to do with the peer type (`Map`). It simply means that the extension method is statically dispatched instead of creating an actual instance of `MapExt` (therefore supposedly it's a bit faster). This is called [value-class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) in Scala.

Comment: @KevinMeredith "per the docs", was there a particular line in the docs that was misleading? The generated code includes a call to the trivial synthetic `MapExt` method, that might be confusing, but doesn't allocate. Also the `Int` result must be unboxed.